# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): result resource in ... on line 25

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подключаю бд, используя код:

```
<?

function db_connect()
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'shop_user';
    $pswd = 'admin123';
    $db   = 'shop';

    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
    if (!$connection || !mysql_select_db($db, $connection)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $connection;
}

function db_result_to_array()
{
    $res_array = array();    
    $count = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
}

function get_products()
{
    db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC";    
    $result = mysql_query($query);    
    $result = db_result_to_array($result);

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\appserver\www\shop\db_fns.php on line 25`

Помогите, пожалуйста, что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну во-первых где сам код, где вы вызываете свои функции?? .ПОтому как вы предсьавили файл с функциями, они сами по себе пока не будут вызваны ошибки не дают.

НО из того что вы представили - у вас ошибка в функции db_result_to_array(), перпешите ее вот так:

```
function db_result_to_array($result)
{
    $res_array = array();    
    $count = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }
    return $res_array;
}
```